# Base radius of a truncated cone

Tags: geometry

The diagram in my paper shows a plastic cup in the shape of a cone with the end removed.

The vertical height of the cone is 20 cm
The height of the cup is 8 cm
The base of the cup has a radius of 2.7 cms

It then asks me to prove that the radius of the top of the cup is 4.5 cms.

(Note that the vertex of the cone is pointing downwards)

Comment: P.S We have not covered trigonometry at school

Answer (score 0):

You don't need trigonometry to do this, it is a problem with similar triangles.

Look at a cross section of the cone. This forms a triangle. The radius of a the cone is $\frac12$ the length of the base, or the side on top. First, we start with a triangle that is 12 (20-8) cm tall, and has a base of $2.7\times2=5.4$ (Because the radius of the bottom of the cup is 2.7 cm). Now we need to make a similar triangle that is 20 cm tall and find the length of the base. This triangle is $\frac{20}{12}$ times the size of the original triangle, since the height is 20 and the height of the original triangle is 12, so applying this scale factor gives $14cm\times\frac{20}{12}=20cm$. This means that that we can scale up all the other sides on this triangle by the same amount (property of similar polygons), so the end side is $5.4cm\times\frac{20}{12}=9cm$. Dividing by 2 to get the radius yields 4.5 cm.